# как вместо ошибки ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: при введении букв, выводилась мною написанная "ошибка"

Tags: python

```
age = int(input("numb"))

if age < 2:
    print("вариант 1")

if age > 2:
    print("вариант 2")

if age == 2:
    print("вариант 3")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте обработку исключений:

```
try:

    age = int(input("numb"))

    if age < 2:
        print("вариант 1")

    if age > 2:
        print("вариант 2")

    if age == 2:
        print("вариант 3")

except ValueError:

    print("Ошибка")
```

Либо проверяйте введённое пользователем значение перед тем, как сделать `int`:

```
age = input("numb")

if not age.isdigit():  # Вот так вот
    print("Ошибка")
elif int(age) < 2:
    print("вариант 1")
elif int(age) > 2:
    print("вариант 2")
elif int(age) == 2:
    print("вариант 3")
```